# What is the difference between these routes?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

What is the difference between these Routes in react? Which one is correct and which one should I use?

```
<Routes>
          <Route exact path="/" element={<Home />} />
          <Route exact path="/about" element={<About />} />
          <Route exact path="/blog" element={<Blog />} />
</Routes>
```

or

```
<Routes>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
          <Route exact path="/about" component={About} />
          <Route exact path="/blog" component={Blog} />
</Routes>
```

Comment: The first one is how routing is set up in React Router Dom version 6, when the second one is for version 5. It's a version matter.

Comment: Oddly enough, @yousoumar's comment is the only thing here that actually answers the question ***and*** is the only thing that is correct. These are "rough equivalents" between versions, but they are not interchangeable with a version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both of them works almost same, but the one use case I can think of, for using element rather than the component(as most people do) is that you can pass props via the element method(element={<Home your_props={"yay I can pass props!"} />}).

So to summarize, there's no such correct or wrong way to do things in programming, it just depends upon your use case. If one was the wrong way, why would the developer keep it?

I hope I can help you decide which way to go.

Comment: Depending on which version of `react-router` or `react-router-dom` a dev is using then ***one of them is wrong***.

Answer (score 0):

Both are correct, but see the below considerations.

1.In react-router-dom v6, 'Routes' is used instead of 'Switch'.
The first code is thus the v6 format of react-router-dom.

2.In react-router-dom v5, there is no 'Routes'. you have to use
'Switch'. So the second code is v5 format of react router and is correct
when you update the 'Routes' to 'Switch'.

Also in react-router-dom v6, you can easily pass the parameters as props to the child elements, like

```
<Route exact path="/about" element={<About msg={'message to child'}/>}  />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use either one, they both work well. Depending on your setup though one may fit a more complex need. Say like passing props directly to the element attribute instead of the component only